# Expose SQL Server 2016 tables as Rest API without coding with the in built configurations?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am looking to create a simple Rest API call to SQL Server 2016 to expose tables and data.

Is there a way I can achieve this by any in built functionality from SQL Server configurations?

Comment: I don't believe so. There used to be a concept of HTTP Endpoints (which I don't know much about) but that was removed

Comment: First thing that comes to mind, in case you're able to work with .NET, is an ODATA/WebAPI layer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/. That will give you a fairly flexible REST API middleware between client and DB. Doesn't fit your "no coding" requirement though.